# Installing multiple versions of MS Outlook

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, installation

Lately, I've being working quite a lot with html email templates development, so I was thinking that perhaps it would be easier for me to just have installed outlook 2003, 2007 and 2010 for testing these templates under a windows instance on a Virtual Machine.

But unfortunately it seems I can't really install different outlook versions under the same OS. If I install 2003 and then install 2007 it simply replaces the old one. if I install 2010 and then 2007 and 2003 the installations succeed well but then when trying to running the applications it simply crashes.

It seems really difficult to get all those 3 versions to run at the same time.
So I would like to know if some of you have some tips on how to get this working.

I know I could use some online service to just return these layouts screenshots to me, but I found that having control over my own instances of outlook would make the testing phase a bit faster and less expensive.

I also have tried to run outlook under Wine using [WineBottler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/) on a mac but again no success installing these softwares.

If you could help me out on that I would appreciate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use virtualization to run different versions of Outlook using tools like VMWare Thinapp, SpoonStudio, Molebox, BoxedApp, etc.

Comment: I advise boxedapp - it's better solution.